# why i can't make my buttons centered horizontally in table layout

Tags: android, xml, button, layout

what i have is buttons that i have inserted them in table layout and each button has a background image and i have tried all of the ways to make the button centered in each row but it didn't work .. here is my xml code:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
   <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horizontal"
       >
       <TableRow
           android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
           android:layout_gravity="center"

          >
       <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="170sp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"

        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/zebra" 

       />
      </TableRow>
       <TableRow 
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center">
           <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="170sp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/roller" 
       />
  </TableRow>
   <TableRow
       android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
       android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="170sp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:background="@drawable/wooden" />
      </TableRow>
       <TableRow
           android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
           android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="170sp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:background="@drawable/roman" />
     </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
  <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/frame_container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
   </FrameLayout>
    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#ffffff"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="#703534"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: in tablerow, use the width as match parent that will help you,

Comment: i did but it didn't work

Comment: @user3675605 can you provide a picture.

Comment: no i can't because my reputation still low :((

Comment: Try to replace TableRow this properties : android:layout_gravity to this :android:gravity.

Comment: wow it worked can you write as an answer so i can approve it? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to button tag **android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"** if not works then add this tag to tablerow

Answer (score 2):

```
android:gravity="center"
```

use this in each of your tablerow. worked for me.

Comment: see carefully. its android:gravity not android:layout_gravity. use android:gravity in tablerow